# Other ways for creating dynamic two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

Edit:

I've completely revised my question as I have a better idea of what I want to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    const int max_rows = 10; 
    const int max_cols = 10; 

    int *test = new int[max_rows * max_cols]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        test[i] = 1 + (rand() % 100);  
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        cout << "#" << i << " " << test[i] << endl; 
    }

    int *b = &test[0]; 

    cout << *b << endl; 

    int *x = b + (i * sizeof(int) * max_cols) + (sizeof(int) * j); 

    cout << *x << endl; 

    return 0; 

}
```

test is supposed to be my two-dimensional array.

*x is supposed to contain the address of `test[i][j]`
(assume that I have the cin >> i and cin >> j in my code).

where i is the row and j is the column that I want.

But it doesn't seem to be giving me the correct address. Unless I'm silly and reading it wrong.

This is the way that I was told to do the problem.

Comment: You don't need ` * sizeof(int)`. C's pointer arithmetic does that implicitly

Comment: You have edited the code, but the text below is not correct any more, since `test[i][j]` does not exist if you have a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Boost Multidimensional Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is simple way, you need allocate one-dimensional array but use it as 2 dimensional:

```
const int row = 5;
const int col = 7;
int *twoD  = new int[row * col];
std::cout << twoD [4*row + 3]; //sample to access [3][4]
return 0;
```

Comment: this still applies, although it should be made more clear whether 3 and 4 are rows or columns. Currently 3 is the column number and 4 the row number.

Comment: @d2jxp - remove "sizeof(int)" from calculation of *x. Note that my code is still correct